# Finding a normal form for the group given by $\langle a,t| t^{-1}at = a^{2}\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with presentation
$$\langle a,t| t^{-1}at = a^{2}\rangle$$

I want to find a normal form for $G$. That is, a collection of words on the alphabet $\{a,t\}$ such that they represent the elements of $G$ in a unique way. Things that I know:

·) Every element of $G$ can be represented as $t^{n}a^{k}t^{-m}$ for $n,m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n, m \geq 0$.

·) There's a well-defined monomorphism

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
G & \hookrightarrow & GL_{2}(\mathbb{Q})\\
a & \longmapsto & \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} =: A\\
t & \longmapsto & \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} =: T\\
\end{array}
$$
 Then, $t^{n}a^{k}t^{-m} = t^{n'}a^{k'}t^{-m'}$ iff $T^{n}A^{k}T^{-m} = T^{n'}A^{k'}T^{-m'}$, which is equivalent to say
$$m - n = m^{'} - n^{'} \text{ and } \dfrac{k}{2^{n}} = \dfrac{k^{'}}{2^{n^{'}}}$$
From this, how can I get a list of diferent words and conclude that every word in $G$ is one of these words, i.e. remove the redundant words and find the normal form?

Comment: Useful: [Britton's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension#Britton's_Lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a criterion to insure uniqueness. For example, consider the "choice" function $\phi$ such that for any word $w \in G$ :
$$
\phi(w) = \min\{n \geq 0 ~|~ \exists m\geq 0, k\in \mathbb{Z} : t^n a^k t^{-m} = w\} 
$$

This function is well defined from your first bullet point. Any word has a unique reduced word attached to it : if $w = t^n a^k t^{-m}$ then we also have $w = t^{\phi(w)}a^{k2^{\phi(w)-n}}t^{n-m-\phi(w)}$ which is a form that does not depend on $n$, $m$ or $k$ from your second bullet point.